# Pinescript: How to isolate a section of an indicator to calculating based on another candle stick pattern

Tags: pine-script

I'm still very new to Pinescript, but am eagerly learning the language.
I was never really tech saavy, no know programming languages until tinkering with Pinescript.

The indicator I would like to modify to my trading style is called Vumanchu Cipher B: https://www.tradingview.com/script/Msm4SjwI-VuManChu-Cipher-B-Divergences/

It's the Money Flow Indicator, where the calculation can be found from lines 314-316:

```
// RSI + MFI Area
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)
rsiMFIColor = rsiMFI > 0 ? #3ee145 : #ff3d2e
```

Thank you in advance if you can help me out!!

I've been trying my best to see if I can isolate the money flow to use calculations based on Heiken Ashi (HA) Candles instead of using the japanese candles I trade with.

I know I have to use something like these commands:

```
useHA=input(true,"Use heikin ashi candles?")
ha_AP=security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, AP)
```

But keep getting errors when I make attempts to put them all together. :'(((

So I guess to summarize, I'd like the Vumanchu indicator to make calculations based on japanese candles, while the Money Flow calculates based on Heiken Ashi.

I hope this makes sense :')

Answer (score 0):

In this script, `f_rsimfi` is :

```
f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period) - rsiMFIPosY)
```

As you can see, this function already uses `security` function, so you can't call the `security` function again.

You can however, change the `symbol` parameter of the `security` function to use `heikinashi` instead of "regular" candles. You can for example first set an `input` as you wanted:

```
useHA=input(true,"Use heikin ashi candles?")
```

Then decide which `syminfo.tickerid` to use according to this input:

```
t = useHA ? heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) : syminfo.tickerid
```

And finally change the function so it will calculate accordingly:

```
f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(t, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period) - rsiMFIPosY)
```